# buffering of process output causing truncation?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, cat

I have a sample file with 100 lines which I am reading using subprocess with `cat`. However, the output in a queue is always truncated. I suspect it might be due to `cat` buffering its output because it detects a pipe.

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cat file.txt",
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                     stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                     shell=True,
                     bufsize=0)
```

I am using separate threads to read from the stdout and stderr pipes of `cat`:

```
def StdOutThread():
  while not p.stdout.closed and running:
    line = ""
    while not line or line[-1] != "\n":
      r = p.stdout.read(1)
      if not r:
        break
      line += r
      pending_line["line"] = line

    if line and line[-1] == "\n":
      line = line[:-1]
    if line:
      queue.put(("out", line))
```

These threads are started and dump what they read into a queue. The main thread reads from this queue while `cat` is alive.

```
with CancelFunction(p.kill):
    try:
      stdout_thread = threading.Thread(target=StdOutThread)
      stdout_thread.start()
      while p.poll() is None:
        ReadFromQueue()
      while not queue.empty():
        ReadFromQueue()  
    finally:
      running = False
      stdout_thread.join()
```

I have considered using pexpect to overcome this issue but at the same time also want to distinguish stdout and stderr which does not seem possible with pexpect. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure your main thread is exiting the try block before all of the output from `cat` has been read and placed on the queue.

Note that `cat` can exit even if you haven't read all of its output.
Consider this sequence of events:

1. `cat` writes out its last line
2. `cat` exits
3. Before the reader threads have a change to read the last bit of output from `cat` the main thread detects that `cat` has exited (via `p.poll()`)
4. The main thread then exits the try block and sets `running` to false
5. The reader threads exit because `running` is false, but before that
   last input has been read.

Below is a simpler approach which uses *sentinel* values in the queue
to inform the main thread that a reader thread has exited.

If `cat` exits then eventually it will reach EOF on the pipe it is
monitoring. And when that happens it will place None onto the queue
to inform the main thread it is finished. When both reader threads have
finished the main thread can safely stop monitoring the queue and
join the threads.

```
import threading
import subprocess
import os
import time
import Queue
import sys

def pipe_thread(queue, name, handle):
  print "in handlehandle"
  for line in handle:
    if line[-1] == "\n":
      line = line[:-1]
    queue.put( (name, line) )
  queue.put(None)

def main():
    p = subprocess.Popen("cat file.txt",
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         shell=True,
                         bufsize=0)

    queue = Queue.Queue()

    t1 = threading.Thread(target = pipe_thread,
                             args = [queue, "stdout", p.stdout])
    t2 = threading.Thread(target = pipe_thread,
                             args = [queue, "stderr", p.stderr])

    t1.start()
    t2.start()

    alive = 2
    count = 0
    while alive > 0:
      item = queue.get()
      if item == None:
        alive = alive - 1
      else:
        (which, line) = item
        count += 1
        print count, "got from", which, ":", line
    print "joining..."
    t1.join()
    t2.join()

main()
```